# Define $n$ and $\overline{abcd}$ 4 digit number to satisfy equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic-progressions

Define $n \in \mathbb{N}^* $ and $\overline{abcd}$ 4 digit number to satisfy the following equation:
$$
\overline{abcd} + \frac{\overline{abcd}}{6} + \frac{\overline{abcd}}{6^2} + ... + \frac{\overline{abcd}}{6^n} = \frac{6^{n+1} -1}{5}
$$

I've been trying to write up the sum of the geometric progression with $a_1=\overline{abcd}$ and $q=\frac{1}{6}$, and then find an $n$ to get a 4 digit number, but no luck, for $n=4$ for example I don't get a whole number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we have a $4$-digit number $x$ and the equation
$$
x(1+\tfrac16+\tfrac1{6^2}+...+\tfrac1{6^n})=\frac{6^{n+1}-1}{6-1}
$$
where we know that partial sums for the [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) with powers of $q=\frac16$ have the form
$$
1+\tfrac16+...+\tfrac1{6^n}=\frac{1-\frac1{6^{n+1}}}{1-\frac1{6}}=\frac{6^{n+1}-1}{6^{n+1}-6^n}
$$
Dividing by this expression on both sides in the original equation then yields
$$
x=\frac{6^{n+1}-6^n}{6-1}=\frac{6^n(6-1)}{6-1}=6^n
$$
and to have a $4$-digit number we want $3\leq \log_{10}(x)\leq4$ meaning
$$
3\leq \log_{10}(6^n)=n\cdot\log_{10}(6)\leq 4
$$
and we see that
$$
3.855\approx\frac3{\log_{10}(6)}\leq n\leq\frac{4}{\log_{10}(6)}\leq5.140
$$
showing that $n=4,x=6^4=1296$ or $n=5,x=6^5=7776$ will work.